# N-pair loss derivation of the formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function, machine-learning

I am trying to understand how is contrastive learning loss function derived in a really known paper called [Improved Deep Metric Learning with Multi-class N-pair Loss Objective](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2016/hash/6b180037abbebea991d8b1232f8a8ca9-Abstract.html)
, but I fail to reason how they derived
from the formula
$$\log(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \exp(f(x)^Tf(x_i^{-}) - f(x)^Tf(x^+)))$$

this one
$$-\log(\frac{ \exp(f(x)^Tf(x^+))}{\exp(f(x)^Tf(x^{+})) + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \exp(f(x)^Tf(x_i^{-}))})$$

where $\{x_i^-\}$ is a set of $N - 1$ negative **samples**, $x^+$ is positive **sample**, and x is current **sample** and $f: \mathbb{R}^q \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$. All these **samples** have the same domain $\mathbb{R}^d$. If you do not understand what negative,positive and current mean, that is okay, because it is irrelevant at this stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the second to the first it's easy to reconstruct the equality :

$$-\log(\frac{ \exp(f(x)^Tf(x^+))}{\exp(f(x)^Tf(x^{+})) + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \exp(f(x)^Tf(x_i^{-}))}) = $$

$$\log(\frac{\exp(f(x)^Tf(x^{+})) + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \exp(f(x)^Tf(x_i^{-}))}{ \exp(f(x)^Tf(x^+))}) =$$

$$\log(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \frac{\exp(f(x)^Tf(x_i^{-}))}{ \exp(f(x)^Tf(x^+))}) =$$

$$\log(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \exp(f(x)^Tf(x_i^{-})-f(x)^Tf(x^+))) $$

Comment: I am embarrassed, so easy. I hate $exp$ notation, it always confuses me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: you're welcome , yes it appeared complicated but in the end really straightforward

Comment: And ... what would be the derivative of this function?

Comment: @Celso França in respect to which variable?

Comment: It would be interesting to see how this function behaves in relation to the representations $f(x)$, $f(x^+)$, and $f(x_i^-)$.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting a slightly cleaner version of the accepted answer:

$$a = f(x)^Tf(x^+)$$
$$b = f(x)^Tf(x_i^{-})$$

$$-\log\left(\frac{e^a}{e^a + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} e^b}\right) = $$

$$\log\left(\frac{e^a + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} e^b}{e^a}\right) = $$

$$\log\left(\frac{e^a}{e^a} + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \frac{e^b}{e^a}\right) = $$

$$\log\left(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \frac{e^b}{e^a}\right) = $$

$$\log\left(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} e^{b-a}\right) $$

$$\log\left(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} e^{f(x)^Tf(x_i^{-}) - f(x)^Tf(x^+)}\right) $$